Change Linux build from shared ncurses5w to static causes a symbol has different size in shared object message?
Because the older ncurses5w is becoming harder to find, I changed the build to use /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncursesw.a and added tinfo as a shared library to link with.
However if I move the binary to a different linux distro (both debian based and both 686) and run it I get:
Symbol `_nc_prescreen' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Symbol `_nc_globals' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking

Since ncurses is no longer using the shared library, I presume this must have something to do with the tinfo library?
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb7f58000)

Both systems so.5 points to so.5.9 (although the dates and size are different)
I'm not sure why it's complaining?
Do I have to static link tinfo or is something else going on here?
TIA!!

Why ever link to one statically and the other dynamically?

Does this answer your question? C++ symbol has different size in shared object
